# Casting nothing into value type: different behavior depending on the number of indirection

Tags: vb.net, types, casting, directcast

In VB, i have different behavior with `DirectCast` and casting into value type (`double`, `int`, ...) depending of the number of indirection

```
DirectCast(nothing, Double)
return 0
```

But, if I try to cast something like a element of a matrix equals to nothing, there is an exception

```
Dim pArray as Object() = { nothing, 1.5, 2.27, -3.0}
DirectCast(pArray(1), Double)  'work with no issue
DirectCast(pArray(0), Double)  'Exception : Cannot convert to double
```

In the same way :

```
Dim TestCasting as object = nothing
Directcast(TestCasting, double) 'Exception : Cannot convert to double
```

How can i make so the `DirectCast` of `pArray(0)` work the same way than `DirectCast(nothing, double)` ?

---

My post was an example that highlight the issue without any concerns for the rest of the code.

To be thrill. here is an example that could pose some issue. Let's take a random table (no primary key or anything but never mind) :

```
TABLE [dbo].[IDENTIFICATION] (
    [USER_ID]        INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [PASSWORD]       NVARCHAR(50)   NULL,
    [EXPIRATION_D]   DATETIME       NOT NULL,
    [LAYOUT]         INT            NULL,
);
```

Now, I have a method which returns an Object(,)

```
Dim pArray as Object(,)  = myconnection.GetSqlRequest("Select USER_ID, PASSWORD, EXPIRATION_D, LAYOUT from IDENTIFICATION where USER_ID = 3")
```

this may return something like `{ 3, "StackOverflow", New Date(2110,01,01), nothing}`  because layout is an optional field.

I can do as such:

```
if pArray(0,3) is nothing then
   Layout = 0
Else 
   Layout = DirectCast(pArray(0,3), Double)
End if
```

But my goal would be to just do :

```
Layout = DirectCast(pArray(0,3))
```

mostly because I'm refactoring a huge part of a code i didn't write and also because it bugs me that `DirectCast(nothing, Double) return 0` except in this case.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18320/DirectCast-Vs-CType

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's simple: don't use `Nothing` when you store `Doubles` in an array and don't use a `Object()` when you actually want to store doubles.

Wait, it would be better to use a `Double?()` anyway. Nullables can be initialized with `null/Nothing` Then you don't need a cast at all.

```
Dim pArray As Double?() = {Nothing, 1.5, 2.27, -3.0}
Dim first = pArray(0)
If first.HasValue Then
    ' No, it's a Nullable(Of Double)/Double? without a value
End If
```

**Edit** According to your original question. The better question would be why this works in VB:

```
Dim d as Double = DirectCast(Nothing, Double) ' => 0.0
```

The reason: `Nothing` in VB.Net is the equivalent of `default(T)` in C#: the default value for the given type which is 0 for numeric types, `Date.MinValue` for `Date` and `Nothing`(now in the meaning of  `null` in C#) for reference types.

So `DirectCast(Nothing, Double)` will be converted implicitely to the `Double` 0. Whereas the `Object()` contains really objects which is a placeholder for everything. But `Nothing` is normally a "unknown" state of any object and not a double, so the `DirectCast` which is very strict fails. It would also throw a runtime error if you would change the value `-3.0` to `-3` since that is actually an `Integer`.

To cut a long story short,

**use `CType` instead of `DirectCast` for those conversions and it'll work.**

```
Dim obj As Object() = {Nothing, 1.0, 2}
Dim d1 = CType(obj(0), Double) ' => 0.0
Dim d2 = CType(obj(1), Double) ' => 1.0
Dim d3 = CType(obj(2), Double) ' => 2.0
```

Comment: Hi,

The Object() is a the return value of a method who query the database.
So, , pArray is mostly like that : 

Dim pArray as Object() = { 1, "string", New Date(2013, 01, 02), Nothing }

Shoud i just check each time if the value is null ?

Comment: @user1942487: Can you change that method? Why does a method which selects numbers return objects?

Comment: Hi, sorry, I miss clic on the enter, i just edit my comment !

Comment: @user1942487: So your method returns anything, strange. How do you want to cast the string or the date to double? That looks like you should refactor your code earlier, probably in that method or even in the database.

Comment: I just edit my initial post. 

I have a easy solution (just check if the data is nothing) but at least you may understand a bit more my issue and i would really love to know why DirectCast on a object who is null don't do the same thing as DirectCast(nothing, Double)

Comment: @Fl0: i would create a custom class which holds all of your columns as properties. Then you could return an instance of this class(f.e. `Identification`) or an `IEnumerable(Of Identification)` if it might return multiple objects. That would be a much better approach.

Comment: What about any result of an sql query ? :)
I.e : 
"Select * from TABLE_1 inner join TABLE_2 on TABLE_1.second_table_id = TABLE_2.ID" 

I can't create a class for that. But still would to cast any element of my Object(,) into different type.

My main question is mostly why it has two different behaviour and how can I cast efficiently a value who can be null.